# Unable to print the Queried list in flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Form.py

```
Release_choices=[('R1', 'R1'), ('2', 'R67')]
class ReleaseviewForm(FlaskForm):
    releaseno=SelectField('ReleaseView',choices=Release_choices,validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

models.py

```
class Date(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    release=db.Column(db.Integer,unique=True,nullable=False)
    product=db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    yesno=db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    duration=db.Column(db.Integer,nullable=False)
    pmfreq=db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    compreq=db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
    cestory=db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Date('{self.product}')"
```

routes.py

```
@Release.route('/releaseview', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def releaseview():
    form = ReleaseviewForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit:
        d=Date.query.filter_by(release=form.releaseno.data).all()
    return render_template('releaseview.html', form=form,d=d)
```

HTML

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container" style="width: 30%;border: 1pt solid purple;padding: 2%" >
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" style="border-bottom: 1pt solid white"> Applied Comps!</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.releaseno.label(class_="form-control-label")}}
{{ form.releaseno(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}

{{form.submit(class_="btn")}}
</div>
</form>
<ul>
{%for u in d%}
    <li>{{u}}</li>
{%endfor%}
</ul>
</div>

{%endblock contents%}
```

Is the for loop not working or the query is wrong?
I tried the loop and query in CMD,it works fine
No error is thrown while executing, but the for loop results are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There can be two checks :

> 1.)

Change you model :

```
release=db.Column(db.String,unique=True,nullable=False)
```

Convert while filtering as a validation.

```
d=Date.query.filter_by(release=str(form.releaseno.data)).all()
```

> 2.)

Print the value like this to print the release no., product :

```
{%for u in d%}
    <li>{{u.release}}</li>
    <li>{{u.product}}</li>
{%endfor%}
```